# Remove titles on buttons and panels ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I have some bug with django-ckeditor: titles on all buttons and panels

[image]

I can't find config parameter to disable it.

```
django-ckeditor==5.0.1
```

Config:

```
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    …
    'simple': {
        'toolbar': [
            ['Source'],
            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline',],
        ],
        'height': 100,
        'width': '100%',
        'toolbarCanCollapse': False,
        'forcePasteAsPlainText': True,
        'autoParagraph':    False,
    },
    …
}
```

In model:

```
class TextPart(models.Model):

    text =       RichTextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=u'Текст', config_name='simple')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's conflict with django-suit:

The problem in this css-rule (suit/static/suit/css/suit.css)

```
.form-horizontal .inline-related span{display:inline-block;}
```

I'm overwrite the suit bast template

templates/admin/base.html

```
  …
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'suit_ck/css/suit.css' %}" media="all">
  …
```

Then copy `suit.css` to `suit_ck/css/suit.css` and remove bug-rule